# Java Морской бой без масива

Tags: java, морской-бой

Всем привет! Есть вот такая задача (это курсы) и я нуждаюсь в помоще с алгоритмом программы, а также советами по роботе с класами обертками(Long, BigInteger  и тд).
Основное задание этого урока - научиться работать с этими класами. Но идей как их сойденить с  задачай пока 0. Была идея создать перечисление из всех 64 точок поля с их двоичним 64 разрядным кодом. Но она не увенчалась успехов потому что в long можна засунуть ток 63 разряда(как я понял).

Реализуйте методы в классе Battleship8x8.

Battleship8x8 представляет собой карту 8x8 для игры в Морской бой. Обратите внимание, что Battleship8x8 использует:

```
поле ships типа long для хранения местоположения кораблей,
поле shots типа long для регистрации выстрелов.
```

Поле типа long хранит 64 бита. Рассматривайте их как 8 строк по 8 ячеек:

```
биты "0" представляют собой пустые ячейки
биты "1" представляют собой ячейки, занятые кораблями или выстрелами.
```

Используйте следующие методы:

```
public boolean shoot(String shot) - регистрирует выстрел и возвращает true, если выстрел попадает в корабль. Выстрел – это комбинация одной из букв английского алфавита от "А" до "H" и одной из цифр от 1 до 8.
public String state() - возвращает строку, представляющую состояние карты. Строка карты состоит из 8 строк по 8 символов, разделенных "\n". Используйте следующие символы:
    '.' - пустая ячейка
    '×' - пустая ячейка, в которую стреляли
    '☐' - ячейка, захваченная кораблем
    '☒' - ячейка, захваченная расстрелянным кораблем.
```

Нельзя добавлять или изменять новые поля. Используйте статические методы классов-оболочек.

**Пример**

Возьмем информацию о карте, закодированную в виде значения long:

```
long map = -1150950973573693440L;
```

Его можно представить как двоичный литерал:

```
/*
    11110000
    00000111
    00000000
    00110000
    00000010
    01000000
    00000000
    00000000
 */
long map = 0b11110000_00000111_00000000_00110000_00000010_01000000_00000000_00000000L;
```

Строки помечены цифрами, а столбцы - буквами:

```
/*
    ABCDEFGH
   ┌────────
  1│11110000
  2│00000111
  3│00000000
  4│00110000
  5│00000010
  6│01000000
  7│00000000
  8│00000000
 */
```

Возьмем список выстрелов:

```
List<> shots = List.of("A1", "B2", "C3", "D4");
```

Зарегистрируем их, используя Battleship8x8 API, и выведем, что получилось:

```
Battleship8x8 battle = new Battleship8x8(map);
shots.forEach(battle::shoot);
System.out.println(battle.state());
```

Результат будет следующим:

```
☒☐☐☐....
.×...☐☐☐
..×.....
..☐☒....
......☐.
.☐......
........
........
```

Comment: `long` вмещает 64 бита.

Comment: https://prntscr.com/26qqb2w - пример побитового числа (64 бита)
https://prntscr.com/26qqbad  - пробую преоброзовать в Long -  получаю ошыбку. Число слишком большое

Comment: Обе проблемы, которые вы показали связаны с преобразованиями в `long` из других типов. Там будут ошибки. Сдругой стороны вы можете в `long` записать и прочитать любой бит с номерами от 0 до 63.

Answer (score 0):

`long` вмещает 64 бита. Проверьте сами:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LongBits {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println("Enter \"1 23\" to set bit 23, \"0 23\" to drop bit 23.");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        long value = 0;
        for (; ; ) {
            for (int i = 63; i >= 0; --i) {
                long bit = 1L << i;
                System.out.print(((value & bit) != 0) ? 1 : 0);
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("> ");
            int bit = s.nextInt();
            int i = s.nextInt();
            if (bit == 0) {
                value &= ~(1L << i);
            }
            if (bit == 1) {
                value |= 1L << i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ javac LongBits.java && java LongBits 
> Enter "1 23" to set bit 23, "0 23" to drop bit 23.
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
> > 1 63
> 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
> > 1 62
> 1100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
> > 1 1
> 1100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010
> > 1 0
> 1100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011
> > 0 0
> 1100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010
> > 0 63
> 0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010
> >
> ```